# Do admins need OP on a Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I used to run a Minecraft server and always gave admins OP. I have seen many abusing it, but when I deopped the best admins, they complained about not having enough rights.

Giving OP to someone is a big risk. Though when giving OP it can also be a big advantage.

So my question is: is it smart to give admins OP? Do they really need it? Of course only **when you trust them**?

Comment: Smart in what sense?  What do you expect them to do with the privileges that being an OP gives?

Comment: @Frank There is a very big number of events that can occur that admins have to solve. With OP, they'll have the rights to do so. If I give the needed rights for a 'normal' situation to the admin rank, I'll have to add the permission(s) manually.

Comment: Generally speaking: every player does require OP, including admins. Though it is (usually) automatically assigned to admins, but regular users require it to be assigned.

Comment: WHat do these admins have to do? DO you use some sort of usergroup/rights plugin? Is this default minecraft or a bukkit server? Or a Forge Server?

Comment: @Ben I don't understand your comment. Why would a normal user need OP?

Comment: @Arperum Yes, I use PermissionsEx. I use Spigot (fork of Bukkit).

Comment: I'm speaking very generally. Even in private servers, every player that joins, requires to be Opped the first time they join.

Comment: @Ben No, they don't. Why would they need that?

Comment: @ben Giving all users op is completely unneeded, you can have a server where there is never anyone op.

Comment: @Arperum Agreed.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. Are you referring to something similar to the `/op [player]` command?

Comment: @Ben Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Well by my understanding of it, the command allows players to place/destroy blocks in a certain area. If a player doesn't have op, and you need them to have this functionality, they need op. Whether it's wise or not is up to you/up to the situation.

Comment: @Ben You are still not understanding the question, and also Minecraft I guess. OP is **not** required to place or destroy blocks. If you protect a certain area with e.g. WorldGuard, you have to give them the permission, that's correct. With OP this is possible too, but it is certainly not required! OP is simply a command to give a user all permissions available (unless explicitly removed with a permissions plugin).

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards In default minecraft the spawn is protected vs modifications by non-ops, so ben *is* right, but so are you

Comment: @Arperum Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down all to the result of trust. I once administrated a server and encountered much of such issue. Primarily with my first batch of recruitments. What there occurred is that they abused the rights to their own benefits. I would recommend you to better understand who you are recruiting before giving them the rights.

As you have mentioned you already have a permissions plugin. I would also suggest that you create a tiered hierarchy. It should have similarities to the following model:

> User -> Trial-Mod -> Moderator -> Admin -> Owner

What this allows is for you to observe your moderators/admins through ghosting. Either being `/vanish` or other means. If you then deem them of a poor admin/mod, you then are free to demote them under such rules. As the owner of the server, you have the final judgement of who should be an admin and receive such rights.

Down to your question for whether admins require OP. I would answer NO. Admins never need OP. OP grants them full autonomy of the server except in some cases such as PEX or GM, where permissions have to be granted specifically. Admins should also NEVER require the `*` node in permissions. You should only grant the permissions they really require and if they bring up that they require more permissions, fully consider the repercussions of granting such commands and give them to the appropriate ranks.

---

The following section shows how you can slowly move over to this system if you already have an existing hierarchy. First lay out a message of similar contents to the following:

> It has come to my attention that many of the admins have been abusing the rights given to them. It is detrimental to the community of the server and thus is unacceptable.

Following this, create a tiered hierarchy that have only what they need to resolve issues. If a mod is there to provide basic support such as LogBlock query and not rollbacks, only give such permission and nothing more. If they complain, remind them the issue you have faced and they have to earn your trust to gain more power.

Pick out a few of the admins you think that does not abuse the power and give them the permission they required permissions. They would respond to issues brought up by the mods and perform the required tasks.

In this hierarchy, The moderators have permissions to do basic checking and not any form of changing(check for griefing and not rollback) and respond to basic questions by the community. If more pressing matters arise, it should be sent to the admins and they should follow up. As for the trial-mod, they would only answer questions and if something does actually fall into the category of admin, alert the mod or admin to settle the issue.

What is happening here is that you should only give permissions to those that you trust and even so only permissions that they require to solve the issue. A mod should not have worldedit commands neither should admins have the permission to kill the server. The most critical of issues such as crashes should only be solved by you and a handful you really trust.

---

After reading your comments, I have seen that the reason you are reluctant to do so is due to the configuring of the permission nodes. I would give a suggestion as a person who once administered a server.

You always want to do permissions even though its the hardest to do. It may be the most tedious, but when you set up a proper hierarchy, with inheritance and the such, not much is really needed in there. After considering everything. I did not have much in my permissions of the admin as most of it is inherited from the moderator. The tediousness of configuring the permissions actually results in an amazing result and reduces complains from the user of abused commands. Spend 2 hours sitting down and do the configs would not hurt. After that you can relax from the quietness of having issues solved by admins and no complains from the users.

In all its entirety, it is **NEVER** recommended to give admins OP unless you fully and utterly trust them. By giving OP, you give them your server. If they world edit away the whole map (as has happened before because someone I trust forgot to move a corner of the selection and deleted the whole map, crashing the server in the process) you are toast. You may still have control over the machine but your community is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. If you use a plugins like Group Manager - Essentials. That should allow you to make a group for your admins, and give them only the permissions you want them to have (without them having to be op).
[Group Manager - Essentials](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Group_Manager)
There is a easy to follow tutorial to the plugin on the page. You should be able to learn to make your own groups in 15-20 minutes of reading.
If you do not want to go to the config file every time you want to edit a group it can be done with in-game commands (more info about that on the page itself).

Edit: You might have to search a little on google to find more information about the config reprogramming. You are always welcome to comment on this answer if you need help :)

Comment: I already have a permissions plugin. This answer does not answer my question. Please re-read the question. (>> they complained about not having enough rights.)

Comment: In that case simply add the asked rights to their permissions group. I think you should instead look at which permissions they need and not which bunch of permission they should have. Choose which permission you want to give them and which permission you dont want to give them. If they keep complaning, find some other way to give them tools. You are the owner of the server., you decide how the server should run.

Comment: @TheBird956 I think you guys are missing the point of the question. There are many different cases an admin has to solve with a set of rights. For certain situations, they may not have the sufficient rights to solve such a problem. So should I just give them OP to prevent problems like these or shouldn't I?

Comment: if you fully trust your admins i dont see a problem in them having up. If you do not trust them i suggest using a permission plugin and giving the the rights they need.
i'm sorry if i did not understand the question corretly.